# How to make a shared XAML Page between different projects in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Let's say I have ten Apps. I also have a project with an "AboutPage" that downloads feeds from my blog. I don't want to recode or copy & paste that page and it's logic in every project of my Apps; also if I made some update to that page, I would like them to be visible to the other projects.

I think I would need to reference the page into the other projects, but I can I solve the problem of the different namespaces and so on?

Is a good idea making a custom control like a "MyBlogFeedReader" and put it into a page?

Comment: did you tried adding it as a link. when you say Add Existing item, the Add button rather become a dropdown with "Add as link" option.So that if you make any update you need not to do any refresh.

Comment: This is a good question. I'm currently porting my app to UWP and I'm forced to copy/paste my XAML. Not ideal. I'll keep you posted with my findings.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a runtime component and move the xaml page into it. Then reference the runtime component into your different projects.

I have a similar runtime component SharedXAML and have a xaml page SharedPage defined in it. In other project, it's so easy to navigate to the page as below:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SharedXAML.SharedPage));
```